# Restrict Customer Item Pricing in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, sublist

Good afternoon,
We've had a question come up which I can't find the answer to, in relation to the Item Pricing sublist on Customer Records in Netsuite.
Basically we want to know if it is possible to Restrict Access to this sublist, so anyone who has access to Customer Records can View the sublist, but only Users with certain Roles can actually Edit the sublist.
Is there any native functionality, or possibly customisation, that could do this?
I haven't been able to find anything in Role Permissions, but I could be overlooking something.
Appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: I don't believe this can be done via Standard Customisation, so I'm guessing we'd be looking at a script.

Comment: Is there a way of scripting access to sublists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially a UserEvent with N/serverWidget or last resort will be JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this has been sorted out by now, but I have done something similar to this.

One of our clients did not want their sales reps to have access to the information on the pricing of an item.

To achieve this, I made a custom form that was the exact same as the standard, except I removed the pricing sublist from the form on creation.

Then on the role record under the forms subtab, the item sublist, I ticked only that customised form for inventory parts.

This meant all with that role can only see that inventory part form. ie, no pricing information.

Comment: That's a slightly different scenario Stephen, but an interesting solution. Will keep that in mind, thank you!